# SQL Server - calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I need to create a column in a view which is derived as below.

The calculated column is derived from `Amount` column where a row value is derived by subtracting from previous row value of `Amount`, and every 1st contract that starts will have no value as it's the first row of that contract.

Can someone please suggest what option I have to achieve this?

| Contract | DateValue | Amount | Calculated Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 20-June-2023 | 100 |  |
| 111 | 21-June-2023 | 150 | 50 |
| 111 | 21-June-2023 | 250 | 100 |
| 111 | 21-June-2023 | 200 | 50 |
| 222 | 20-June-2023 | 300 |  |
| 222 | 21-June-2023 | 350 | 50 |
| 222 | 22-June-2023 | 450 | 100 |
| 333 | 23-June-2023 | 100 |  |
| 333 | 24-June-2023 | 200 | 100 |
| 333 | 24-June-2023 | 250 | 50 |

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You can't do this as a computed column; they can only refer to columns in the same row. You would be better off using a `VIEW` if you want this readily queriable.

Comment: I'm using a View, How do i do it in view.

Comment: Side note: the format of your dates implies you are storing them as a string based; I hope *not*.

Comment: Have you had a look at `LAG`/`LEAD`? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I have not explored LAG/LEAD, can you share some other answer that i can refer. New to SQL.

Comment: [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)/[LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16); the documentation contains plenty of examples.

Comment: I think LAG can solve the problem of getting previous value, But how do I reset it when new Contract Starts. Any Suggestion on that.

Comment: Why is the 4th row computed value being reported as _positive_, given that it is a decrease?

Comment: *"But how do I reset it when new Contract Starts."* You don't; you partition those groups. Think in "sets", tables **don't** contain a set of *ordered* rows.

Comment: [Subtract previous row value to current row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129588/subtract-previous-row-value-to-current-row)

Comment: I'm only interested in absolute difference of 2 values, Positive and negative are irrelevant for my business purpose, Hence 4th row value is also positive.

Comment: You don't mention that in your question, @Govindchouhan , you just state *"by subtracting from previous row"*, which actually means that all but the row queried above should be negative values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to do it using window function `LAG()` to get the previous value :

```
select *, Amount - lag(Amount) over (partition by Contract order by DateValue) as [Calculated Column]
from mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/A11AC-GD)

Answer (score 0):

Your data has no way to determine the order of duplicate DateValues so I will assume you also have an identity id column.
(A relation is an unordered set!)

Why does 200 - 250 = 50?

```
SELECT id, [Contract], DateValue, Amount
   ,Amount -
      LAG(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY [Contract] ORDER BY DateValue, id) AS CalcValue
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Only Absolute value is needed in Difference, Hence Positive 50.